# Python - Split tab delimited file and convert to dataframe

Tags: python, list

This is the line I copy and pasted from the file:

```
UNBILL REC        18041667.97    55851351.64           0.00          0.00           0.00   -57467160.72          33.28     -1615775.80    16425892.17
```

I believe is tab delimited that I'm using the following code:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as file_handle:
    example_file_content = file_handle.read().split("\n")
alignmentMatrix = []
for index, line in enumerate(example_file_content):
    if "UNBILL REC" in line:
        print(re.split(r'\t+',line.lstrip()))
        alignmentMatrix.append(re.split(r'\t+',line.lstrip())) 
alignmentDF = pd.DataFrame(alignmentMatrix)
```

The problem is that this gives me a list like:

```
['UNBILL REC         4166047.25     3498767.15           0.00          0.00           0.00    -3058993.54           0.00       439773.61     4605820.86']
```

When converted to a dataframe then, all values are put into one column, instead of one value for each column.

My expected output would be:

```
['UNBILL REC','4166047.25','3498767.15','0.00','0.00','0.00','-3058993.54','0.00','439773.61','4605820.86']
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: You sound like you're not certain the input is tab-delimited, and the output in your post has spaces, not tabs (assuming you copy-pasted it verbatim).

Comment: I copy and pasted the line from the file as well as posted my output and what the expected output should be. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, and the data you copied - assuming it was not transformed in any way - does not have any tabs, it has spaces. So you should actually split on spaces to make this work (but keep in mind that `UNBILL REC` also has an internal space).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign `re.split()` of `alignmentMatrix[0]` to a Dataframe:

```
re.split('\s{2,}',alignmentMatrix[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not read the file as if it was a csv? Then transpose it

```
df = pandas.read_csv("file.txt", sep="\t")
df_tr = df.transpose()
```

Comment: Unfortunately the file has many different shapes and when I tried the above, the output looked too far away from a solution even when reading in specific lines.